Modify tooltip for bar graph in oracle apex
I am working on oracle apex 22.2. How can we modify the labels which are shown inside a tooltip for a bar graph?enter image description here
like change the label Series to something else in the above image
I couldn't find any option in apex to directly modify the tooltip labels
